# Disable replying to cases from personal emails

Tags: email2case, servicecloud, org-wide-defaults

New case is created and assigned to a support queue, users from tech team re assign cases to themselves but I want to make sure all the emails are going from support email address instead of their personal emails.

Is there a way to set default reply from email to be always support? Or maybe there is a way to disable personal emails to make sure nothing would go out from personal emails?

Comment: When the emails are getting sent from which point you would like to restrict them?

Comment: I'd want to have functionality to reply from queue emails e.g. support@ instead of letting people to reply from their personal emails

Comment: Hi NGix - Have you found a work-around for this yet?

Comment: Yes, was thinking of two options: 1) implement QuickActionDefaultsHandler interface (didn't go this route) ref https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_QuickAction_QuickActionDefaultsHandler.htm. 2) Limit emails shown from case feed layout and restrict access to some of the emails from permission sets (solution was needed for specific user profile)